# Subsetting a data frame to the rows not appearing in another data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a data frame A with observations

```
    Var1   Var2  Var3
     1       3    4
     2       5    6
     4       5    7
     4       5    8
     6       7    9
```

and data frame B with observations

```
    Var1   Var2  Var3
     1       3    4
     2       5    6
```

which is basically a subset of A. 
Now I want to select observations in A NOT in B, i.e, the data frame C with observations

```
    Var1   Var2  Var3
     4       5    7
     4       5    8
     6       7    9
```

Is there a way I can do this in R? The data frames I've used are just arbitrary data.

Answer (score 10):

`dplyr` has a nice `anti_join` function that does exactly that:

```
> library(dplyr)
> anti_join(A, B)
Joining by: c("Var1", "Var2", "Var3")
  Var1 Var2 Var3
1    6    7    9
2    4    5    8
3    4    5    7
```

Answer (score 5):

Using sqldf is an option.

```
require(sqldf)

C <- sqldf('SELECT * FROM A EXCEPT SELECT * FROM B')
```

Comment: You should install the "sqldf" first: install.packages("sqldf")

Answer (score 5):

Another option:

```
C <- rbind(A, B)
C[!(duplicated(C) | duplicated(C, fromLast = TRUE)), ]
```

Output:

```
  Var1 Var2 Var3
3    4    5    7
4    4    5    8
5    6    7    9
```

Answer (score 4):

One approach could be to paste all the columns of `A` and `B` together, limiting to the rows in `A` whose pasted representation doesn't appear in the pasted representation of `B`:

```
A[!(do.call(paste, A) %in% do.call(paste, B)),]
#   Var1 Var2 Var3
# 3    4    5    7
# 4    4    5    8
# 5    6    7    9
```

One obvious downside of this approach is that it assumes two rows with the same pasted representation are in fact identical. Here is a slightly more clunky approach that doesn't have this limitation:

```
combined <- rbind(B, A)
combined[!duplicated(combined) & seq_len(nrow(combined)) > length(B),]
#   Var1 Var2 Var3
# 5    4    5    7
# 6    4    5    8
# 7    6    7    9
```

Basically I used `rbind` to append `A` below `B` and then limited to rows that are both non-duplicated and that are not originally from `B`.

Answer (score 4):

Using [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) you could do an anti-join as follows:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[!df2, on = names(df1)]
```

which gives the desired result:

```
   Var1 Var2 Var3
1:    4    5    7
2:    4    5    8
3:    6    7    9
```